# How to use locale entity in js-code

Tags: firefox-addon

is it possible to get the value of an entity

```
<!ENTITY gatwayError  "Gateway error">
```

**using javascript**? For now I reference them in my xul file using

```
&gatewayError;
```

**UPDATE:** In my `ff-sidebar.xul` within the `<page>` I have

```
<stringbundleset id="stringbundleset">
    <stringbundle id="strings" 
                  src="chrome://myaddon/locale/de/sidebar.properties"/>
</stringbundleset>
```

In my `ff-sidebar.js` I do on click:

```
var strbundle = document.getElementById("strings");
var localizedString = strbundle.getString("test");
```

This gives me following error

[image]

Should it not be

```
var strbundle = document.getElementById("stringbundleset");
```

This gives me no error but no result too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically what Neil posted there is what you need to do (minus first paragraph rant :P )

Here's an example (basically digest from Neil's links):

Your XUL file:

```
<stringbundleset id="strbundles">
    <stringbundle id="strings" src="chrome://yourextension/locale/something.properties"/>
</stringbundleset>
```

Your something.properties (there you define your localized strings key=value). Of course you can have as many files as you want/need:

```
something=Some text for localization
something2=Some more text
```

Your js file:

```
var strbundle = document.getElementById("strings");
var localizedString = strbundle.getString("something");
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: this is exactly the way I do it but it does not work, I set the stringbundleset within the <page> of my ff-sidebar.xul and access it just like you showed it but it does not work, and firebug gives no errors

Comment: have you tried alert(strbundle); just to see if you're getting something. Also alert(localizedString); - poor man's debugging, I know :)

Comment: chrome://myaddon/locale/de/sidebar.properties is not correct, you should be using chrome://myaddon/locale/sidebar.properties (without de or en or any other locale specifier) and use document.getElementById("strings")

Comment: Thanks!! I removed the "de" and it works, however the file is in the ../de path...

Comment: yes, that's the point :) - firefox will use de, en, es, ... depending on localization requirement

Answer (score 1):

This works for small numbers of entities. For instance, menuitems sometimes have two entities with slightly different text depending on what the menuitem will be used for, and the correct entity is then copied to the label. The worst abuse of this was for the Delete menuitem in Thunderbird and SeaMonkey's mail windows, which had labels for unsubscribing from newsgroups, deleting folders, cancelling news posts, deleting single or multiple messages, or undeleting single or multiple messages from folders using the IMAP mark as delete model. Phew!

If you have lots of locale data then the best thing is to put it in its own `.properties` file and read it using a [`<stringbundle>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/stringbundle). If your script doesn't have access to a `<stringbundle>` element it is also possible to manually retrieve an [nsIStringBundle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nsIStringBundle) from the [nsIStringBundleService](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIStringBundleService).

Comment: What part of stringbundles would you like an example for? I already gave you three links...